# How to get "cast like" adaption to work with pure zope.interface?

Tags: python, zope.interface, zope.component

I would like to get the "C++ cast like" adaption to work with the code from `zope.interface`. In my real use case, I'm using a registry from `Pyramid` but it derives from `zope.interface.registry.Components`, which according to the changes.txt was introduced to be able to use this stuff without any dependency on `zope.components`. And the following example is complete and self contained:

```
from zope.interface import Interface, implements                                 
from zope.interface.registry import Components  

registry = Components()                                                          

class IA(Interface):                                                             
    pass                                                                         

class IB(Interface):                                                             
    pass                                                                         

class A(object):                                                                 
    implements(IA)                                                               

class B(object):                                                                 
    implements(IB)                                                               
    def __init__(self,other):                                                    
        pass                                                                     

registry.registerAdapter(                                                        
    factory=B,                                                                   
    required=[IA]                                                                
)                                                                                

a = A()                                                                          
b = registry.getAdapter(a,IB) # why instance of B and not B?                                                 
b = IB(A()) # how to make it work?
```

I wonder why `registry.getAdapter` already returns the adapted object, which is an instance of `B` in my case. I would have expected to get back the class `B`, but perhaps my understanding of the term adapter is wrong. As this line works and obviously the adapting code is registered correctly, I would also expect the last line to work. But it fails with an error like this:

> TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <....A object at 0x4d1c3d0>,
>   < InterfaceClass ....IB>)

Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `IB(A())` work, you need to add a hook to the the `zope.interface.adapter_hooks` list; the `IAdapterRegistry` interface has a dedicated `IAdapterRegistry.adapter_hook` method we can use for this:

```
from zope.interface.interface import adapter_hooks

adapter_hooks.append(registry.adapters.adapter_hook)
```

See [Adaptation](http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/README.html) in the `zope.interface` README.

You can use the [`IAdapterRegistry.lookup1()`](http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/adapter.html#lookup1) method to do single-adapter lookups without invoking the factory:

```
from zope.interface import providedBy

adapter_factory = registry.adapters.lookup1(providedBy(a), IB)
```

Building on your sample:

```
>>> from zope.interface.interface import adapter_hooks
>>> adapter_hooks.append(registry.adapters.adapter_hook)
>>> a = A()
>>> IB(a)
<__main__.B object at 0x100721110>
>>> from zope.interface import providedBy
>>> registry.adapters.lookup1(providedBy(a), IB)
<class '__main__.B'>
```